# Having trouble running setup-environment (YOCTO) in a Ubuntu 32-bit VM

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation

I am running a 32-bit Ubuntu in VirtualBox on my i7-64 bit System and was following steps to build YOCTO; In the process, I have to run the following command

```
$ MACHINE=smarch-samx6i ../setup-environment build
```

to which the response is always

```
bash: ../setup-environment: No such file or directory
```

Then, ldd also says it is not a dynamic executable;

```
$ ldd setup-environment
not a dynamic executable
```

What's the problem? My system is definitely 32-bit as confirmed by `uname`

Answer (score 1):

The file is in the current directory `.` not the parent directory `..` so you are simply using the wrong address

```
MACHINE=smarch-samx6i ./setup-environment build
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this works..but

```
MACHINE=smarc-samx6i source setup-environment build
```

works alright instead of the given instruction using `MACHINE=smarc-samx6i ../setup-environment build`.